# Simple HTML DOM Parser - find class inside another class

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have this HTML script:

```
<div class="find-this">I do not need this</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="find-this">I need this</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="find-this">I need this</div>
    <div class="find-this">I need this as well</div>
</div>
```

So far, I have this:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=content]') as $key => $element) :
        $result = $html->find('div[class=find-this]', $key)->innertext;
        echo $result;
endforeach;
```

How do I find the `find-this` class that is inside the `content` class, and not the one above, without knowing how many are inside the needed class and how many are outside? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath might be what you are looking for. With this code you get only the three nodes that you need.

```
/* Creates a new DomDocument object */
$dom = new DomDocument;
/* Load the HTML */
$dom->loadHTMLFile("test.html");
/* Create a new XPath object */
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
/* Query all <divs> with the class name */
$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[@class='content']//div[@class='find-this']");
/* Set HTTP response header to plain text for debugging output */
header("Content-type: text/plain");
/* Traverse the DOMNodeList object to output each DomNode's nodeValue */
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
    echo "Node($i): ", $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

Note: I based my answer on [this other related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13718745/1252947).